# Java Set array to full

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void addItem() 
{
    boolean items = false;
    System.out.println("Enter item name");
    item = sc.nextLine();
    while (item.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        item = "unknown";
    }
    System.out.println("Enter item type");
    itemType = sc.nextLine();
    while (!itemType.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")
            && !itemType.equalsIgnoreCase("no")
            && !itemType.equalsIgnoreCase(null)) {
        System.out.println("Please enter yes or no only");
        itemType = sc.nextLine();
    }
    if (itemType.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
        items = true;
    else if (itemType.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
        items = false;
    if (itemList.addItem(new Item(item, itemType)))
        System.out.println("Item added successfully\n");
    else
        System.out.println("Shop is full\n");
}
```

My itemList class

```
public boolean addItem(Item anItem) 
{
    // if the array is full, return false
    // if the array is not full, add the item to the array and
    // increment counter
    if (count == items.length) {
        return false;
    } else {
        items[count] = anItem;
        count++;
        return true;
    }
}
```

What are the possible ways for me to add `System.out.println("Shop is full")` at the start whenever my array is full and new data can be added when my array is not full? 
What I have tried was the shop is full will be displayed in the end whenever my array is full, however, I want it to be displayed in the beginning instead of in the end. Any help here?

Comment: I don't see any array in this code.

Comment: What is `itemList`. What is the expected behaviour? can you be clearer what it does now, what it should do, and what you tried? Can you give an actual complete example? input, output, etc?

Comment: itemList is specified from another class. I have updated the question

Comment: did you attempt to run the code? where is the error exactly?

Comment: There are 0 errors, but the line "shop is full" will be displayed in the end whenever my array is full, however, I want it to be displayed in the beginning instead of in the end

Comment: i think..the if condition in itemList class is always returning true. and thus that addItem() method returns false. check it out there..once

Answer (score 1):

You can define an `isFull()` method in `itemList` class, and call that method where ever you want. This way you can find out if the list is full before trying to add a new item to it.

```
public boolean isFull()
{
   return (count == items.length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your code entirely, but you can add the following method in your `itemList` class (btw, classes should be named with capital, like ItemList):

```
public boolean isFull(){
    return count == items.length;
}
```

and then in your original code you can just do

```
if(itemList.isFull()){
    System.out.println("Shop is full");
}
else{
    \\rest of code here
}
```

Comment: Is there no another way for me to display it through my first method instead of creating another method in the itemList Class

Comment: You need to make sure that the array is full. the only way of doing it is by accessing it. In case both that array `items` and `count` are public in you `ItemList` class, then you can just write `if(itemList.count == itemList.items.lenght)` in your code, without the need of creating a new method. But it's generally bad practice to make them public. They should be private in most of the cases and be accessed/modified by getters/setters, so the best practice in this case is to add this new method.

Answer (score 0):

in your itemlist class add the following method to check for empty spaces;

```
    public boolean checkSpaces() {
boolean x = true;
       if (this.count == items.length || this.count > items.length) { return false; } 
return x;
    }
```

then at the beginning check for empty spaces

Answer (score 0):

I would think you could add System.out.println(Shop is full) right before you return false in your if statement.

```
public boolean addItem(Item anItem)
    {   // if the array is full, return false
        // if the array is not full, add the item to the array and 
        // increment counter
        if (count == items.length){
            System.out.println(Shop is full)
            return false;
        }
        else{
            items[count] = anItem;
            count ++;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there no another way for me to display it through my first method instead of editing my second method in itemList class

Comment: No, but like others are pointing out if you are planning on using it on both you can extract that piece of code and call in both methods. I think in the end you'll have to do some editing but not much. 8 )